# How do I condense this function?

Tags: jquery

I have this function which, when I click a button, another `div` will be shown, and another `div` will be hidden. The code works, but it's sloppy. Is there any good ideas how to shorten the function down?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#page-1-button").click(function(){
        $("#page-2").css('display','inline');
        $("#page-1").css('display','none');
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:'0px'},300)
    });

    $("#page-2-button").click(function(){
        $("#page-3").css('display','inline');
        $("#page-2").css('display','none');
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:'0px'},300)
    });

    $("#page-2-button-back").click(function() {
        $("#page-1").css('display','inline');
        $("#page-2").css('display','none');
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:'0px'},300)
    });

    $("#page-3-button-back").click(function(){
        $("#page-2").css('display','inline');
        $("#page-3").css('display','none');
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:'0px'},300)
    })
});



<div id="page-1"> <input id="page-1-button" /> </div>
<div id="page-2"> <input id="page-2-button" /> <input id="page-2-button-back" /> </div>
<div id="page-3> <input id="page-3-button-back" /> </div>
```

Comment: Could you please post your HTML as well.

Comment: "Minify" generally means obfuscate. You're not after doing that. Also SO is _not_ a personal code vending machine!

Comment: The html is like this


<div id="page-1">
<input id="page-1-button" />
</div>
<div id="page-2">
<input id="page-2-button" />
<input id="page-2-button-back" />
</div>
<div id="page-3>
<input id="page-3-button-back" />
</div>

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing working code. Please consider asking this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your HTML, you may want to look at manipulating elements in relation to the button:

Not knowing your HTML structure, I'll guess:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.page').show();
        $(this).next('.page').hide();
...etc...
})
```

This way the same code can work for all of the elements using class names and relative DOM positions, without needing to make a specific call for each ID.

Answer (score 0):

One thought

```
function showHideControls(div1, div2){
   $(div1).show();
   $(div2).hide();
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:'0px'},300); 

  }
$("#page-1-button").click(function(){  
    showHideControls('#page2','#page1');
});  

$("#page-2-button").click(function(){  
        });  

$("#page-2-button-back").click(function() {  

});  

$("#page-3-button-back").click(function(){  
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Install this jquery plugin:
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

Then :

```
$(':regex(id,^page-[0-9]-button$)').click(function(){
        var n = parseInt($(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];)
        $("#page-"+(n+1).toString()).css('display','inline');
        $("#page-"+n).css('display','none');
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:'0px'},300)
    });

    $(':regex(id,^page-[0-9]-button-back$)').click(function() {
        var n = parseInt($(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];)
        $("#page-"+(n-1).toString()).css('display','inline');
        $("#page-"+n).css('display','none');
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:'0px'},300)
    });
```

this should work, but if it adds to actual speed or anything... not sure about that. And it really doesnt remove any lines as you have to add this regexp plugin... But if there will be  many many more of those buttons, then this script should be more dynamic than having to write events for all the buttons.

Comment: It seems like a nifty sollution - but the whole point of the post was that i wanted to make the whole function much shorter :(

Answer (score 0):

With this, you can add new pages.

```
$("div").map(function() {
    var id_string,
    index,
    back_face,
    number_pattern,
    backface_pattern;
    id_string = $(this).attr('id');
    number_pattern = /\d+/;
    backface_pattern = /back$/gi;
    if (id_string.match(/.+-(\d+)-.+(-back)?$/gi) !== null) {
        index = parseInt(number_pattern.exec(id_string));
        if (backface_pattern.exec(id_string) === 'back') {
            $("#page-" + index.toString()).hide();
            $("#page-" + (index + 1).toString()).show();
        } else {
            $("#page-" + (index + 1).toString()).hide();
            $("#page-" + index.toString()).show();
        }
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: '0px'
        },
        300);
    }
});
```

This reduces your code by 36.11% while the condensed version (removing white spaces but still readable) ...

```
// in your javascript file...
$("div").map(function() {
  var id_string, index, back_face, number_pattern, backface_pattern;
  id_string = $(this).attr('id');
  number_pattern = /\d+/;
  backface_pattern = /back$/gi;
  if (id_string.match(/.+-(\d+)-.+(-back)?$/gi) !== null) {
    index = parseInt(number_pattern.exec(id_string));
    if (backface_pattern.exec(id_string) === 'back') {
      $("#page-" + index.toString()).hide();
      $("#page-" + (index + 1).toString()).show();
    } else {
      $("#page-" + (index + 1).toString()).hide();
      $("#page-" + index.toString()).show();
    }
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:'0px'},300);
  }
});
```

**EDIT**: And you do not necessarily need a plugin

This reduces the code by a whooping 66.67%

Comment: Can't get it to work : |

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#page-1-button").click(function(){
$("#page-2").show();
$("#page-1").hide();
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:'0px'},300);
});
```

you can do for rest

Comment: Why no indentation? And how does this code otherwise differ from the original?